# vim surrround ideavim - Surrounding visually selected text adds class attribute to end tag

Tags: ideavim

I am using IdeaVim on pycharm with Vim surround plugin. The issue i am having is that when i try to surround a visually selected text inside html tag that has class as well, it adds the class attribute to the end tag as well. Here is the example code

`<p>Hello</p>`

So I want to wrap this line inside a `div` tag so I select the line visually and then hit `S and the result i see is as below

```
<div class="container"><p>Hello</p>
</div class="container">
```

This does not happen with normal vim surround plugin installed on my vim and here is the output from normal vim.

```
<div class="container">
<p>Hello txt</p>
</div>
```

So is it issue with Ideavim emulated plugin or am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the vim-surround emulation in IdeaVim. Feel free to report it to the [bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).

You might also be interested in other issues related to the vim-surround emulation. See [this query](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM?q=%23surround%20) in the bug tracker.